# Тайминг анимации css

Tags: html, css

Есть 4 текста и 8 картинок. По одному тексту на 2 картинки. Текст должен менять цвет на красный как только поменялась картинка и оставаться таким на протяжении 2-х картинок и потом менять цвет снова на черный. Как только появляется 3 картинка снова красный до тех пор пока не пройдет 4 картинка и тд. У меня проблема с таймингом. Как ее исправить?

```css
    .div-wrap {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

/* Текст */

.div-txt p {
  color: black;
  font: bold 16px 'Arial';
  text-align: center;
  animation-duration: 24s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: color-change;
}
.div-txt:nth-child(1) p:nth-child(1) { animation-delay: 0s; }
.div-txt:nth-child(1) p:nth-child(2) { animation-delay: 6s; }
.div-txt:nth-child(3) p:nth-child(1) { animation-delay: 12s; }
.div-txt:nth-child(3) p:nth-child(2) { animation-delay: 18s; }

/* Картинки */

.div-img { position: relative; height: 240px; width: 300px; }

.div-img img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  display: block;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  opacity: 0;
  animation-duration: 24s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: fade;
}
.div-img img:nth-child(1) { animation-delay: 0s; }
.div-img img:nth-child(2) { animation-delay: 3s; }
.div-img img:nth-child(3) { animation-delay: 6s; }
.div-img img:nth-child(4) { animation-delay: 9s; }
.div-img img:nth-child(5) { animation-delay: 12s; }
.div-img img:nth-child(6) { animation-delay: 15s; }
.div-img img:nth-child(7) { animation-delay: 18s; }
.div-img img:nth-child(8) { animation-delay: 21s; }

/* Анимации */

@keyframes color-change {
  0%, 25%, 100% { color: black; }
  1%, 24% { color: red; }
}
@keyframes fade {
  0%, 13%, 100% { opacity: 0; }
  1%, 12% { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Адаптивность */

@media all and (min-width: 740px) {
  .div-wrap {
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="div-wrap">
  <div class="div-txt">
 <img src="img/connect.svg" style="width: 36px; height: 36px;">
    <p>Connect</p>
      Text,Text,Text,Text,Text,Text,Text,Text,<br>Text,Text,Text,Text,Text,Text
      <img src="img/connect.svg" style="width: 36px; height: 36px;">
    <p>Calibrate</p>
     Text,Text,Text,Text,Text,Text,Text,Text,<br>Text,Text,Text,Text,Text,Text
  </div>
  <div class="div-img">
    <img src="img/mockups/1.png" title="Image 1" style="width: 600px; height: 600px;">
    <img src="img/mockups/2.png" title="Image 2" style="width: 600px; height: 600px;">
    <img src="img/mockups/3.png" title="Image 3" style="width: 600px; height: 600px;">
    <img src="img/mockups/4.png" title="Image 4" style="width: 600px; height: 600px;">
    <img src="img/mockups/5.png" title="Image 5" style="width: 600px; height: 600px;">
    <img src="img/mockups/6.png" title="Image 6" style="width: 600px; height: 600px;">
    <img src="img/mockups/7.png" title="Image 7" style="width: 600px; height: 600px;">
    <img src="img/mockups/8.png" title="Image 8" style="width: 600px; height: 600px;">
  </div>
  <div class="div-txt">
   <img src="img/connect.svg" style="width: 36px; height: 36px;">
    <p>Train</p>
     Text,Text,Text,Text,Text,Text,Text,Text,<br>Text,Text,Text,Text,Text,Text
     <img src="img/connect.svg" style="width: 36px; height: 36px;">
    <p>Analyze</p>
     Text,Text,Text,Text,Text,Text,Text,Text,<br>Text,Text,Text,Text,Text,Text
  </div>
</div>
```

то что сверху абзацев это иконки, и после их вставки тоже не горит или горит сразу 3 текста и видно что картинки меняются. т.е у меня есть мокап в котором они должны меняться, помогите с этим тоже). как это решить?

Comment: Лучше `JS`, чем такая простыня `css`

Comment: Прости, щас занят... Если до вечера ни кто не ответит, обещаю без внимания вопрос не оставить....

Comment: @Juicy134 немного непонятно - когда цвет меняется с красного на чёрный? Если красный появляется с первой картинкой, держится и на второй, а на третьей - он снова красный... Т.е. как появился, так ему некогда было поменяться на чёрный.

Comment: @Air я тоже хочу глянуть твоё решение на JS. Должно получиться прилично меньше кода, чем на чистом CSS. Сам бы сделал, но не всё ж одному мне "спасибы" получать))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я вижу решение так:

```css
.div-wrap {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

/* Текст */

.div-txt p {
  color: black;
  font: bold 16px 'Arial';
  text-align: center;
  animation-duration: 24s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: color-change;
}
.div-txt:nth-child(1) p:nth-child(1) { animation-delay: 0s; }
.div-txt:nth-child(1) p:nth-child(2) { animation-delay: 6s; }
.div-txt:nth-child(3) p:nth-child(1) { animation-delay: 12s; }
.div-txt:nth-child(3) p:nth-child(2) { animation-delay: 18s; }

/* Картинки */

.div-img { position: relative; height: 240px; width: 300px; }

.div-img img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  display: block;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  opacity: 0;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  animation-duration: 24s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: fade;
}
.div-img img:nth-child(1) { animation-delay: 0s; }
.div-img img:nth-child(2) { animation-delay: 3s; }
.div-img img:nth-child(3) { animation-delay: 6s; }
.div-img img:nth-child(4) { animation-delay: 9s; }
.div-img img:nth-child(5) { animation-delay: 12s; }
.div-img img:nth-child(6) { animation-delay: 15s; }
.div-img img:nth-child(7) { animation-delay: 18s; }
.div-img img:nth-child(8) { animation-delay: 21s; }

/* Анимации */

@keyframes color-change {
  0%, 25%, 100% { color: black; }
  1%, 24% { color: red; }
}
@keyframes fade {
  0%, 13%, 100% { opacity: 0; }
  1%, 12% { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Адаптивность */

@media all and (min-width: 740px) {
  .div-wrap {
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="div-wrap">
  <div class="div-txt">
    <p>business</p>
    <p>cats</p>
  </div>
  <div class="div-img">
    <img src="//picsum.photos/300/240?image=998" title="Image 1">
    <img src="//picsum.photos/300/240?image=535" title="Image 2">
    <img src="//picsum.photos/300/240?image=593" title="Image 3">
    <img src="//picsum.photos/300/240?image=219" title="Image 4">
    <img src="//picsum.photos/300/240?image=841" title="Image 5">
    <img src="//picsum.photos/300/240?image=1011" title="Image 6">
    <img src="//picsum.photos/300/240?image=1016" title="Image 7">
    <img src="//picsum.photos/300/240?image=976" title="Image 8">
  </div>
  <div class="div-txt">
    <p>sports</p>
    <p>nature</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

UPD:1 После изменения разметки

```css
.div-wrap {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Текст */

.div-txt p.label {
  color: black;
  font: bold 16px 'Arial';
  animation-duration: 24s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: color-change;
}
.div-txt:nth-child(1) p.label:nth-child(2) { animation-delay: 0s; }
.div-txt:nth-child(1) p.label:nth-child(5) { animation-delay: 6s; }
.div-txt:nth-child(3) p.label:nth-child(2) { animation-delay: 12s; }
.div-txt:nth-child(3) p.label:nth-child(5) { animation-delay: 18s; }

/* Картинки */

.div-img { position: relative; height: 600px; width: 600px; border: 2px solid #ccc; }

.div-img img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  display: block;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  opacity: 0;
  animation-duration: 24s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: fade;
}
.div-img img:nth-child(1) { animation-delay: 0s; }
.div-img img:nth-child(2) { animation-delay: 3s; }
.div-img img:nth-child(3) { animation-delay: 6s; }
.div-img img:nth-child(4) { animation-delay: 9s; }
.div-img img:nth-child(5) { animation-delay: 12s; }
.div-img img:nth-child(6) { animation-delay: 15s; }
.div-img img:nth-child(7) { animation-delay: 18s; }
.div-img img:nth-child(8) { animation-delay: 21s; }

/* Анимации */

@keyframes color-change {
  0%, 25%, 100% { color: black; }
  1%, 24% { color: red; }
}
@keyframes fade {
  0%, 13%, 100% { opacity: 0; }
  1%, 12% { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Адаптивность */

@media all and (min-width: 1170px) {
  .div-wrap {
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="div-wrap">
  <div class="div-txt">
    <img src="img/connect.svg" style="width: 36px; height: 36px;">
    <p class="label">Connect</p>
    <p>Text,Text,Text,Text,Text,Text,Text,Text,<br>Text,Text,Text,Text,Text,Text</p>
    <img src="img/connect.svg" style="width: 36px; height: 36px;">
    <p class="label">Calibrate</p>
    <p>Text,Text,Text,Text,Text,Text,Text,Text,<br>Text,Text,Text,Text,Text,Text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="div-img">
    <img src="img/mockups/1.png" title="Image 1" style="width: 600px; height: 600px;">
    <img src="img/mockups/2.png" title="Image 2" style="width: 600px; height: 600px;">
    <img src="img/mockups/3.png" title="Image 3" style="width: 600px; height: 600px;">
    <img src="img/mockups/4.png" title="Image 4" style="width: 600px; height: 600px;">
    <img src="img/mockups/5.png" title="Image 5" style="width: 600px; height: 600px;">
    <img src="img/mockups/6.png" title="Image 6" style="width: 600px; height: 600px;">
    <img src="img/mockups/7.png" title="Image 7" style="width: 600px; height: 600px;">
    <img src="img/mockups/8.png" title="Image 8" style="width: 600px; height: 600px;">
  </div>
  <div class="div-txt">
    <img src="img/connect.svg" style="width: 36px; height: 36px;">
    <p class="label">Train</p>
    <p>Text,Text,Text,Text,Text,Text,Text,Text,<br>Text,Text,Text,Text,Text,Text</p>
    <img src="img/connect.svg" style="width: 36px; height: 36px;">
    <p class="label">Analyze</p>
    <p>Text,Text,Text,Text,Text,Text,Text,Text,<br>Text,Text,Text,Text,Text,Text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

UPD:2 Переменная для скорости

```css
.div-wrap {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: center;
}

:root{
  --time: 24; /* Скорость переключения */
}

/* Текст */

.div-txt p.label {
  color: black;
  font: bold 16px 'Arial';
  animation-duration: calc(var(--time) * 1s);
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: color-change;
}
.div-txt:nth-child(1) p.label:nth-child(2) { animation-delay: 0s; }
.div-txt:nth-child(1) p.label:nth-child(5) { animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 4 * 1s); }
.div-txt:nth-child(3) p.label:nth-child(2) { animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 2 * 1s); }
.div-txt:nth-child(3) p.label:nth-child(5) { animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 1.33 * 1s); }

/* Картинки */

.div-img { 
  position: relative;
  height: 600px;
  width: 600px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(153,153,153,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
}
.div-img img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  display: block;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  opacity: 0;
  animation-duration: calc(var(--time) * 1s);
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: fade;
}
.div-img img:nth-child(1) { animation-delay: 0s; }
.div-img img:nth-child(2) { animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 8 * 1s); }
.div-img img:nth-child(3) { animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 4 * 1s); }
.div-img img:nth-child(4) { animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 2.66 * 1s); }
.div-img img:nth-child(5) { animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 2 * 1s); }
.div-img img:nth-child(6) { animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 1.6 * 1s); }
.div-img img:nth-child(7) { animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 1.33 * 1s); }
.div-img img:nth-child(8) { animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 1.14 * 1s); }

/* Анимации */

@keyframes color-change {
  0%, 25%, 100% { color: black; }
  1%, 24% { color: red; }
}
@keyframes fade {
  0%, 20%, 100% { opacity: 0; z-index: auto; }
  1%, 99% { z-index: 1; }
  8%, 12% { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Адаптивность */

@media all and (min-width: 1170px) {
  .div-wrap {
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="div-wrap">
  <div class="div-txt">
    <img src="img/connect.svg" style="width: 36px; height: 36px;">
    <p class="label">Connect</p>
    <p>Text,Text,Text,Text,Text,Text,Text,Text,<br>Text,Text,Text,Text,Text,Text</p>
    <img src="img/connect.svg" style="width: 36px; height: 36px;">
    <p class="label">Calibrate</p>
    <p>Text,Text,Text,Text,Text,Text,Text,Text,<br>Text,Text,Text,Text,Text,Text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="div-img">
    <img src="//picsum.photos/600/600?image=998" title="Image 1">
    <img src="//picsum.photos/600/600?image=535" title="Image 2">
    <img src="//picsum.photos/600/600?image=593" title="Image 3">
    <img src="//picsum.photos/600/600?image=219" title="Image 4">
    <img src="//picsum.photos/600/600?image=841" title="Image 5">
    <img src="//picsum.photos/600/600?image=1011" title="Image 6">
    <img src="//picsum.photos/600/600?image=1016" title="Image 7">
    <img src="//picsum.photos/600/600?image=976" title="Image 8">
  </div>
  <div class="div-txt">
    <img src="img/connect.svg" style="width: 36px; height: 36px;">
    <p class="label">Train</p>
    <p>Text,Text,Text,Text,Text,Text,Text,Text,<br>Text,Text,Text,Text,Text,Text</p>
    <img src="img/connect.svg" style="width: 36px; height: 36px;">
    <p class="label">Analyze</p>
    <p>Text,Text,Text,Text,Text,Text,Text,Text,<br>Text,Text,Text,Text,Text,Text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ты не хуже моего `js-ом` знаком, напиши вторым ответом.... Красиво сделано, держи плюс

Comment: @UModeL Спасибо, Гений! За все!

Comment: @Juicy134 _"Семь раз отмерь, один раз отрежь"_ Сколько Вы ещё переделывать будете? Да и посчитать не проблема. Нарисовать на бумажке, для наглядности. Но, лень же, да?.. Будет время,тогда гляну.

Comment: @UModeL СПАСИБО!

Comment: @UModeL я могу вам в чат написать?

Comment: @UModeL тут же вроде можно в чате писать, чтобы в комментах не писать все

Comment: @UModeL я видоизменил, и теперь не работает, поэтому хотел списаться, если у вас время есть

Comment: @Juicy134 у Вас должен быть макет того, что вы хотите. Когда есть макет, сначала в HTML создаются все необходимые блоки, статичные тексты и т.д. Затем, с помощью CSS, позиционируем и оформляем. На этом этапе, возможно задание анимаций, если того требует дизайн и интерфейс, и не задействуются скрипты. Далее, задаётся поведение и логика в скиптах (JS), в зависимости от действий пользователя, и для дополнительной манипуляции элементами. Как видите, HTML-разметку мы не трогаем после первого шага и не выдумываем на ходу. Ваш подход может растянуть работу на месяцы.

Answer (score 1):

```css
@keyframes fadeIm-1
{
    0%{ 
        transform: scale(0.5);
        opacity: 0,5; 
    }
    6.25% {
        transform: scale(1);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    18.75% {
        transform: scale(0);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes fadeIm-2
{
    0% {
        transform: scale(0);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    6.25% {
        transform: scale(0);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    18.75%{ 
        transform: scale(1);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    31.25% {
        transform: scale(0);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes fadeIm-3
{
    0% {
        transform: scale(0);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    18.75% {
        transform: scale(0);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    31.25%{ 
        transform: scale(1);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    43.75% {
        transform: scale(0);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes fadeIm-4
{
    0% {
        transform: scale(0);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    31.25% {
        transform: scale(0);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    43.75%{ 
        transform: scale(1);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    56.25% {
        transform: scale(0);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes fadeIm-5
{
    0% {
        transform: scale(0);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    43.75% {
        transform: scale(0);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    56.25%{ 
        transform: scale(1);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    68.75% {
        transform: scale(0);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
@keyframes fadeIm-6
{
    0% {
        transform: scale(0);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    56.25% {
        transform: scale(0);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    68.75%{ 
        transform: scale(1);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    81.25% {
        transform: scale(0);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
@keyframes fadeIm-7
{
    0% {
        transform: scale(0);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    68.75% {
        transform: scale(0);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    81.25%{ 
        transform: scale(1);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    93.75% {
        transform: scale(0);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
@keyframes fadeIm-8
{
    0% {
        transform: scale(0);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    81.25% {
        transform: scale(0);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    93.75%{ 
        transform: scale(1);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(0.5);
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
}
.div-style
{
    position: relative; 
    text-align: center; 
    width: 99%; 
}

.img-style
{   position: absolute;
    width: 33.3%;
    margin-top: 8px;
    border: 1px solid #0000ff;    
    animation-duration: 20s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
/*.img-style.next
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 33.3%;
    opacity: 0;
}*/
.img-style.im-1
{ 
    animation-name: fadeIm-1;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    transform: scale(0);
}
.img-style.next.im-2
{ 
    animation-name: fadeIm-2;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    transform: scale(0);
}
.img-style.next.im-3
{
    animation-name: fadeIm-3;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    transform: scale(0);
}
.img-style.next.im-4
{
    animation-name: fadeIm-4;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    transform: scale(0);
}   
.img-style.next.im-5
{
    animation-name: fadeIm-5;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    transform: scale(0);
}   
.img-style.next.im-6
{
    animation-name: fadeIm-6;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    transform: scale(0);
}   
.img-style.next.im-7
{
    animation-name: fadeIm-7;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    transform: scale(0);

}
.img-style.next.im-8
{
    animation-name: fadeIm-8;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    transform: scale(0);
}

@keyframes color-change {
    0% { color: red; }
    49% {color:red;}
    50% { color: black; }
    99% {color: black;}
    100% { color: red; }
} 

p{
    -webkit-animation: color-change 10s infinite;
    -moz-animation: color-change 10s infinite;
    -o-animation: color-change 10s infinite;
    -ms-animation: color-change 10s infinite;
    animation: color-change 10s infinite;
}






@-webkit-keyframes color-change {
    0% { color: red; }
    50% { color: blue; }
    100% { color: red; }
}
@-moz-keyframes color-change {
    0% { color: red; }
    50% { color: blue; }
    100% { color: red; }
}
@-ms-keyframes color-change {
    0% { color: red; }
    50% { color: blue; }
    100% { color: red; }
}
@-o-keyframes color-change {
    0% { color: red; }
    50% { color: blue; }
    100% { color: red; }
}
```

```html
<p>Text1</p>
    <p>Text2</p>
    <p>Text3</p>
    <p>Text4</p>

    <div class="div-style">
        <img alt="1" title="Image 1" class="img-style im-1">
        <img alt="2" title="Image 2" class="img-style next im-2">
        <img alt="3" title="Image 3" class="img-style next im-3">
        <img alt="4" title="Image 4" class="img-style next im-4">
        <img alt="5" title="Image 4" class="img-style next im-5">
        <img alt="6" title="Image 4" class="img-style next im-6">
        <img alt="7" title="Image 4" class="img-style next im-7">
        <img alt="8" title="Image 4" class="img-style next im-8">
    </div>
```

На 1 цвет текста приходят 2 картинки.

Comment: скорость поменял, а ост не понял /*чтобы в одной рамке появлялись? Т.е как у меня, а поменять просто скорость текста?*/